# Item doesn't get deleted using Kendo UI MVVM

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

Please refer to the code below. On pressing the delete button, I want to delete the list item containing delete button. 
The issue is item doesn't get deleted.

Thanks for your time and help.

```
     <div id="example">

         <div id="invitationsDiv">
                    <ul id="invitationsPanelBar" data-template="template"  data-bind="source: invitations">
                    </ul>
         </div>
         <script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">

               <li>#= userName # <button data-bind="click: deleteProduct">Delete</button>
                 <ul>   
                    <li>                    

                             #= invitationList.text # 
                            #if (invitationList.state === "new") {#
                                New
                            #}#

                  </li>
                </ul>   
               </li>
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

              var viewModel = kendo.observable({

              deleteProduct: function(e) {
                        var invitation = e.data;
                        var invitations = this.get("invitations");
                        var index = invitations.indexOf(invitation);
                        invitations.splice(index, 1);
                    },
                    invitations: [{"userName":"user1", "invitationList": {"text":"Check LV", "state": "new"}},{"userName":"user2", "invitationList": {"text":"Check NY", "state": "read"}}, {"userName":"user3", "invitationList": {"text":"Check NY", "state": "new"}} ]
                 });

                kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);

                $("#invitationsPanelBar").kendoPanelBar({

                });

            });
        </script>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the PanelBar is initialized from your array but doesn't use it a `source` (it is not an `observable` object). I.e. changes in the `invitations` array are not reflected in the `PanelBar`.

You can see in the following example (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qb3su/) that while the "deleted" element does not get removed from the `PanelBar` it gets removed from a `ListView` that uses the same `invitations` as `DataSource`.

For removing them, you should do something like:

```
deleteProduct: function(e) {
    var pbar = $("#invitationsPanelBar").data("kendoPanelBar");
    pbar.remove($(e.currentTarget).closest("li"));
},
```

But this will not reflect the change in the PanelBar DataSource as you can see it in http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qb3su/1/